# How would i apply a custom function on a torch dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

so i'm using the twitter dataset for sentiment analysis and created my own function to remove the username handles from the text

```
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("carblacac/twitter-sentiment-analysis", "None")
```

the dataset contains three keys for the train_set, val_set, test_set

My function for removing the username is not the most elegant but it does seem to work

```
def remove_username(text: str):
  #sep text  on spaces
  splitted_text = text.split(sep = " ")
  counter = 0
  returned_text = ""
  for text in splitted_text:
    #skip the 0 index where username is stored
    if counter != 0:
      #since the text was split by space when we add a text we have to include the space
      returned_text += " " + text
    #increment counter  
    counter += 1
    #return text
  return returned_text
```

My question is whats the best way to apply this function on the dataset['train'], I did have a look at dataloader and thought i could prehaps apply this as a transform lambda function but didn't see the option available, next i thought i could prehaps go through a for loop and apply it to each one, one by one but its taking forever

Answer (score 0):

Users within this database are indicated with an @, I would thus advise using a regex expression to clean the text:

```py
' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word[0]!='@')
```

You can either write a data loading method that converts each string during runtime. This would look like this:

```py
class TwitterDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, text, labels):
        self.text = text
        self.labels = labels

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        label = self.labels[idx]
        sentence = self.text[idx]
        text = ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word[0]!='@')
        sample = {"Text": text, "Class": label}
        return sample

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

An alternative would be to perform the transformation that you need beforehand and then store the data as an update dataset. This would have the advantage of eventually saving computing time.